# Leaflet function 'onEachFeature' not working when I try to show info in a Info Control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am very new in javaScript and Leaflet and probably I am doing something bad, but I can´t figure out. I have a map and six bottom. Every time the user push the diferents bottoms, the markers in the map change to display diferents data. So far, so good. However, I want that when the user move on the mouse over the marker, the info appear in a Custom Info Control in the top right. And there is the problem. I read the tutorial in Leaflet website, and they use the 'onEachFeature' function, but it don't work for me.

There is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Leaflet GeoJSON Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
<style>
    #map {
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .info {
        padding: 6px 8px;
        font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: white;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .info h4 {
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        color: #777;
    }

    .legend {
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 18px;
        color: #555;
    }
    .legend i {
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 8px;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
            <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" onClick="setupPage01();">2006</button>
    <button class="btn" onClick="setupPage02();">2007</button>
            <button class="btn" onClick="setupPage03();">2008</button>
    <button class="btn" onClick="setupPage04();">2009</button>
            <button class="btn" onClick="setupPage05();">2010</button>
    <button class="btn" onClick="setupPage06();">2011</button>
    </div>
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js?2"></script>

 <script>
var points =  {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Italia",
            "time": "2006",
             "radius": 22000
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                12.567379999999957,
                41.87194,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
              {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Grecia",
            "time": "2006",
             "radius": 9050
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                21.824311999999964,
                39.074208,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
                      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "España",
            "time": "2006",
             "radius": 32000
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -3.7492200000000366,
                40.46366700000001,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Malta",
            "time": "2006",
             "radius": 18000
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                14.375415999999973,
                35.937496,
                1
            ]
        }
    }
                            ]
};

var points2 = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [

{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Italia",
            "time": "2007",
             "radius": 19900
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                12.567379999999957,
                41.87194,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
              {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Grecia",
            "time": "2007",
             "radius": 19900
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                21.824311999999964,
                39.074208,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
                      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "España",
            "time": "2007",
             "radius": 18000
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -3.7492200000000366,
                40.46366700000001,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Malta",
            "time": "2007",
             "radius": 18000
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                14.375415999999973,
                35.937496,
                1
            ]
        }
    }

  ]
};

var points3 = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
       {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Italia",
            "time": "2008",
             "radius": 36000
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                12.567379999999957,
                41.87194,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
              {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Grecia",
            "time": "2008",
             "radius": 15300
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                21.824311999999964,
                39.074208,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
                      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "España",
            "time": "2008",
             "radius": 13400
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -3.7492200000000366,
                40.46366700000001,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Malta",
            "time": "2008",
             "radius": 2700
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                14.375415999999973,
                35.937496,
                1
            ]
        }
    }
          ]
};

 var points4 = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [

{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Italia",
            "time": "2009",
             "radius": 9573
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                12.567379999999957,
                41.87194,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
              {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Grecia",
            "time": "2009",
             "radius": 10165
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                21.824311999999964,
                39.074208,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
                      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "España",
            "time": "2009",
             "radius": 7285
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -3.7492200000000366,
                40.46366700000001,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Malta",
            "time": "2009",
             "radius": 1470
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                14.375415999999973,
                35.937496,
                1
            ]
        }
    }
                  ]
};

var points5 = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Italia",
            "time": "2010",
             "radius": 4348
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                12.567379999999957,
                41.87194,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
              {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Grecia",
            "time": "2010",
             "radius": 1765
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                21.824311999999964,
                39.074208,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
                      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "España",
            "time": "2010",
             "radius": 3632
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -3.7492200000000366,
               40.46366700000001,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Malta",
            "time": "2010",
             "radius": 28
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                14.375415999999973,
                35.937496,
                1
            ]
        }
    }
                          ]
};

var points6 = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [

    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Italia",
            "time": "2011",
             "radius": 61000
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                12.567379999999957,
                41.87194,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
              {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Grecia",
            "time": "2011",
             "radius": 1030
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                21.824311999999964,
                39.074208,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
                      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "España",
            "time": "2011",
             "radius": 5443
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -3.7492200000000366,
                 40.46366700000001, 
                1
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Malta",
            "time": "2011",
             "radius": 1574
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                14.375415999999973,
                35.937496,
                1
            ]
        }
    } 
                             ]
};    

var map = L.map('map').setView([40.4,7.7],4);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/34c2e9a12fd4479faf8138690648fafa/22677  /256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 15,
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>   contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
}).addTo(map);

function getSize(d) {
return (d)/1000 ;}

var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); 
this.update();
return this._div;
};

 info.update = function (props) {
 this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Inmigrantes llegados a puertos</h4>' +  (props ?
    '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.radius + ' personas</sup>'
    : 'Pasa el ratón por los circulos');
 };

 info.addTo(map);

 function highlightFeature(e) {
 var layer = e.target;
 info.update(layer.feature.properties);
 };


    var circulos1;
    var circulos2;
    var circulos3;
    var circulos4;
    var circulos5;
    var circulos6;


   function resetHighlight(e) {
   info.update();
   };


   function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
   layer.on({
   mouseover: highlightFeature,
   mouseout: resetHighlight
   });
   }    

    circulos1 = L.geoJson(points, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
 return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
radius: getSize(feature.properties.radius),
fillColor: "#ff7800",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.8,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    });
}
    });

    circulos2 = L.geoJson(points2, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
radius: getSize(feature.properties.radius),
fillColor: "#ff7800",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.8,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
}
});


    circulos3 = L.geoJson(points3, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
radius: getSize(feature.properties.radius),
fillColor: "#ff7800",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.8,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
}
});


    circulos4 = L.geoJson(points4, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
radius: getSize(feature.properties.radius),
fillColor: "#ff7800",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.8,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
}
});


    circulos5 = L.geoJson(points5, {
 pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
 return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
 radius: getSize(feature.properties.radius),
fillColor: "#ff7800",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.8,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
 }
});


    circulos6 = L.geoJson(points6, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
radius: getSize(feature.properties.radius),
fillColor: "#ff7800",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.8,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
}
});

    function setupPage01() {
    map.removeLayer(circulos2)
    map.removeLayer(circulos3)
    map.removeLayer(circulos4)
    map.removeLayer(circulos5)
    map.removeLayer(circulos6)
    map.addLayer (circulos1);
    };

    function setupPage02() {
    map.removeLayer(circulos1)
    map.removeLayer(circulos3)
    map.removeLayer(circulos4)
    map.removeLayer(circulos5)
    map.removeLayer(circulos6)
    map.addLayer (circulos2);
    };

    function setupPage03() {
    map.removeLayer(circulos1)
    map.removeLayer(circulos2)
    map.removeLayer(circulos4)
    map.removeLayer(circulos5)
    map.removeLayer(circulos6)
    map.addLayer (circulos3);
    };

    function setupPage04() {
    map.removeLayer(circulos1)
    map.removeLayer(circulos2)
    map.removeLayer(circulos3)
    map.removeLayer(circulos5)
    map.removeLayer(circulos6)
    map.addLayer (circulos4);
    };

    function setupPage05() {
    map.removeLayer(circulos1)
    map.removeLayer(circulos2)
    map.removeLayer(circulos4)
    map.removeLayer(circulos3)
    map.removeLayer(circulos6)
    map.addLayer (circulos5);
    };

    function setupPage06() {
    map.removeLayer(circulos1)
    map.removeLayer(circulos2)
    map.removeLayer(circulos4)
    map.removeLayer(circulos5)
    map.removeLayer(circulos3)
    map.addLayer (circulos6);
    };

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are defining your GeoJSON layers (circulos1, circolos2,...) you are passing your onEachFeature function as an option to L.circleMarker, when this should be passed alongside pointToLayer as an option to L.geoJson.

If you update all of your layer references to match the one below your customer info control should populate on mouseover and mouseout.

```
circulos1 = L.geoJson(points, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, 
        {
            radius: getSize(feature.properties.radius),
            fillColor: "#ff7800",
            color: "#000",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8                
        });
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
```